# ontotext graphdb fail to lock issue while workbench is up and running

Tags: graphdb

I got up and running standalone graphdb-free-8.4.0 version and a initialised workbench. 
When I try to test Embedded Graphdb connection using maven, it is saying

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) on
>   project my-first-app: An exception occured while executing the Java
>   class. org.eclipse.rdf4j.sail.SailException: Repository under
>   /opt/maven-graphdb-test/graphdb-free-8.4.0/data/repositories/test/storage
>   is currently in use (we failed to lock its lockfile:
>   /opt/maven-graphdb-test/graphdb-free-8.4.0/data/repositories/test/storage/lock)!

I've got to shutdown current workbench to test for embedded connection.

Is there a way to overcome this issue without shutting down workbench.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

GraphDB is a database and like every database it needs an exclusive read/write access to the files to maintain data consistency. The simplest answer is you cannot run multiple database instances over the same data image. You have two options to workaround this problem:

**Run the client against the remote server**

Initialize the client against a server endpoint (http://localhost:7200), but not a file system. In this case, all client requests will be processed by the server so there will be only a single process reading and writing to the database image.

**Run each server with its own data image**

Run the second embedded GraphDB server to use a different `$GDB_DATA` directory. This will create two independent database copies which will not interfere.